# Xamarin Form - ScrollView and its Content

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have created one sample application and in that I have taken one ContentPage and did its design as below

```xml
 <ContentPage>
   <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="scroll">
    <StackLayout HeightRequest="50" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label x:Name="lbl1" Text="label1!" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        <Label x:Name="lbl2" Text="label2" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        <Label x:Name="lbl3" Text="label3" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        <Label x:Name="lbl4" Text="label4" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />   
    </StackLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

It works absolute fine , but when I take ContentView instead of ContentPage , I got blank page on emulator.

Is it bug ? or I did something wrong in this.

Comment: Are you saying that when you replace your `<ContentPage>` tags with a `<ContentView>` you do not see content anymore?

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin.Forms works by bringing [Pages](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Page/) in and out of the view.  A [ContentPage](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ContentPage/) is a Page, but a [ContentView](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ContentView/) is NOT a Page.

If it helps, a ContentView is analagous to a UserControl in WPF.

See [this](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17469/contentview-and-contentpage) forum for some other explanations on the subject.